# Hot Reload Angular & Electron Application

Tags: angular, electron, hot-reload

I have a vanilla Angular 14.x application (just `ng new`) to which I've added Electron 19.x and electron-reload.  Everything works if I run `ng build --base-href ./ && electron .`

Now I'm trying to add hot reloading.  All I want is to have changes I make in my renderer process code to be reflected in the Electron app without having to hard reset Electron.  I've seen many questions and answers on SO, seen several blog articles but for some reason none of it is working for me.  Here are the important parts of my `main.js` (Electron main):

```js
require("electron-reload");  // <-- package is installed

//In my createWindow function:
const url = `file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`;
win.loadURL(url);

//I've also tried: win.loadFile(`${__dirname}/dist/index.html`); (with no difference in the result)
```

The Angular application is entirely unchanged except for editing `angular.json` to

```json
...
 "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            ...
}
...
```

The application loads correctly the first time.  But after I make a change (add extra characters in `app.component.html`), I get the following logged to the console in VSCode:
`(node:4788) electron: Failed to load URL: file:///C:/myProject/dist/ with error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

It seems odd that the failing URL doesn't include the filename - index.html - but I don't know if that matters.  If I look in the `dist` folder, I can see that the file is there.

This is on a Windows machine.  What do I need to do to make this work?